# Why find and exec with multiple conditions doesn't work without parenthesis?

Tags: bash, filesystem

I have two very similar `find` commands only one of which works. Since it's relevant, I must mention that there are no files with `.c` or `.hpp` extensions.

```
# That one works
find ~/src/ \( -type f -iname '*.cpp' -or -iname '*.h' -or -iname '*.c' -or -iname '*.hpp' \) -exec echo {} \;
# That one doesn't
find ~/src/ -type f -iname '*.cpp' -or -iname '*.h' -or -iname '*.c' -or -iname '*.hpp' -exec echo {} \;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, neither work as you expect. Let's look at the one that "doesn't work" and apply the parentheses and logic that are implied.

```
find ~/src \( -type f -a -iname '*.cpp' \) -or \( -iname '*.h' \) -or \( -iname '*.c' \) -or \( -iname '*.hpp' \) -exec echo {} \;
```

No action is applied to files that end in cpp, or file system objects that end in h and c. Only file system objects that end in hpp are echoed because `-exec` negates the default behavior of `find` to print. You could add `-exec echo {} \;` or `-print` at the end of each enclosed parentheses but that's silly.

Let's fix the "one that works"

```
find ~/src -type f \( -iname '*.cpp' -or -iname '*.h' -or -iname '*.c' -or -iname '*.hpp' \) -exec echo {} \;
```

Comment: Is that behaviour of find documented somewhere?

Comment: @assp1r1n3 Read the manual, pay attention to the `-print` option and the OPERATORS heading.

Comment: Still, it's very unclear.